# Page not index in google search console

Tags: development-environment

I recently try to Index 10,000 pages in google search console but it is more than 2 week these pages still not index someone please help me to fix this problem.

Or share any method to index page Quickly.

The site is: `https://www.solutioninn.com/`

Answer (score -1):

As I can see that your website is made in AngularJs version 1. Now, there is hell lots of issues with Angularjs version 1 and Google indexing.

Google bot uses Chromium version 41 to crawl and index websites for the search engine. For having a clear understanding that where your website is failing to get indexed, Download Chromium/Chrome browser version 41 and then load your website and check what errors you are getting in the console. If you are getting a single error your site will not get indexed. You also need to implement proper meta tags.

I have worked extensively on this type of issues. It would be really terrible to write a whole solution here. You can ping me in person. I may help in resolving your issue.